# Batch change name from ABC - DEF.pdf to DEF - ABC.pdf

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I want to batch change 50+ files in a folder in Windows10. the original name style: 'how to install the software - softwareA user manual p1.pdf', the new file name will be 'softwareA user manual p1 - how to install the software.pdf'. I am using a .bat file to do the job and exported a list of all the file names into a .txt file. I want to change each line from 'filename' to 'move filename new_filename'. I can add 'move ' in front of all the lines, but don't know how to generate new filename (swap 2 parts before and after - in the old filename) and append the new filename at the end of each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
:%s/^\(.*\) - \(.*\)\.pdf$/move "&" "\2 - \1.pdf"
```

If you have a file with lines with only file names:

```
how to install the software - softwareA user manual p1.pdf
how to test the software - softwareA user manual p1.pdf
how to use the software - softwareB user manual p2.pdf
```

That substitute command will turn them into:

```
move "how to install the software - softwareA user manual p1.pdf" "softwareA user manual p1 - how to install the software.pdf"
move "how to test the software - softwareA user manual p1.pdf" "softwareA user manual p1 - how to test the software.pdf"
move "how to use the software - softwareB user manual p2.pdf" "softwareB user manual p2 - how to use the software.pdf"
```

Which should actually do everything you're trying to accomplish, including adding the `move` command and quoting the file names, considering they contain spaces.

Trying to disect that regex a bit:

- `\(.*\)` matches a group and saves it in a "group" such as `\1`, `\2`, etc.
- the `-` will match a dash surrounded by spaces, in the middle of the name.
- the `\.pdf` will match a literal ".pdf" extension.
- the `^` and `$` anchors make sure this only matches full lines.

And the expansion:

- `&` expands to the entire text matched, which is the whole filename.
- `\2` and `\1` will expand to the matched groups, but in reverse order.
- so `\2 - \1.pdf` will expand to the new filename you want.
- adding literal quotes with the `"`s.
- and finally including a `move` command.

Finally, the `%` (right after `:`) acts on the whole file (equivalent to a `1,$` range) and `s` is the substitute command.

Save the resulting file as a `.bat` and run it to batch rename all your files. Good luck!